# Symfony, how to create a persistent flash message

Tags: php, symfony

I want to display a flash message that doesn't get removed after being seen.

For example:

- *Your e-mail address isn't verified. Please click on the link inside the email...*" which must be displayed until the user clicks on the verification link.
- *Check out the new features...* This one is dismissable by clicking on the X

What is the best approach to do this? Should I create a db table and read from it at any page view (and if so, how can I pass the result to any controller, and to the base twig layout?), or is there something better?

Comment: Calling it a flash message is a bit confusing, as a flash message is a message that is removed after being seen. What you're asking for has nothing to do with a flash message; you just want a regular message.

Comment: At the beginning I thought I could use the flashbag, but using the session doesn't make sense since they will be gone if he logouts

Comment: Anyway it's not even a "message", a message is something that goes in an inbox and the user can reply

Comment: @the_nuts According to Webster Merriam, a message is [a piece of information that is sent or given to someone](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/message). Anyway, lets not get philosophical here. The point Erik tried to make is that flash messages are not built for what you want to receive. Yes you could construct something which would solve this using flash messages, however using an approach like Alok answered, would be better (in my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

**Flash messages** are meant to be get removed as soon as you retrieve them.

If there are multiple things your user should do and you want to notify them with a message to do the same. Best approach would be to add columns  in user table with for all tasks with false as default status. If the status is `false` then display the message until user completes the task.

When user completes the task make it true.

If you want to perform extensive operations on task them you may create separate table for all the tasks.

By extensive tasks I mean you may want to record the date-time when it gets completed, other important message or description you want to show per task.

Advantage of this in Symfony is when ever user logins you have all the status of tasks along with user's object. So it would be easier for you too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [peek()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages) method instead to retrieve the message while keeping it in the bag.

```
{% for flash_message in app.session.flashBag.peek('notice') %}
    <div class="flash-notice">
        {{ flash_message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```